# RapidMiner: Is there a way to use decision operators like IF, ELSE IF, ELSE, etc

Tags: if-statement, rapidminer

I want RapidMiner to send me an email under certain circumstances.

For example, when the temperature is above a certain set-point.

I've figured out how to send the information I want, I just don't know how to make it only send under certain circumstances, but not under others.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RapidMiner offers you several ways to control the process flow and to act differently under certain conditions.

First of all you can use the *Branch* Operator, which works like a normal `If Then Else` statement. It has an condition input port, if the condition is related to a specific ExampleSet, or you can use a generic expression. You probably need to use [*macros*](http://community.rapidminer.com/t5/RapidMiner-Studio-Knowledge-Base/How-to-Use-Macros/ta-p/32966%22macro%22) in this case

If you need to discern between more than two different options, you can also use the *Select Subprocess* Operator. With it you can select between different sub-processes (similar to a `Switch -Case`block).

Lastly in the case of error handling you can use the *Handle Exception* Operator, that provides a Try-Catch block, so for example you can get a notification if for some reason your an error occurs.

Also feel free to ask further, or re-post, questions in the [RapidMiner community forum](http://community.rapidminer.com).